# Alterar mensagens de campos obrigatórios do wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Boa noite, eu quero trocar a tradução dessas mensagens que aparecem quando o campo não foi preenchido, alguém sabe como alterar? Estou usando o wordpress, já tentei fazer uma busca por algum arquivo que estaria isso, mas não consegui encontrar.

Obrigado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá @Diogo, você está utilizando algum plugin específico para seu formulário de contato? Ou o formulário é padrão to tema que está utilizando? Dependendo da resposta, a forma de tradução pode mudar.

Comment: Boa tarde! Estou usando o padrão e o WooCommerce Extra Checkout Fields for Brazil, para que eu pudesse colocar CPF, RG e selecionar pessoa jurídica e física na hora do cadastro.
Se poder me dar um help, agradeço demais, estou com dificuldade nisso.
Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Este plugin já possui tradução completa para português, talvez seja necessário apenas atualizar o plugin ou arquivo de tradução - através do `wp-admin` mesmo, em `Painel -> Atualizações`, no final desta página, são listadas as traduções para atualização.

---

De qualquer forma, se mesmo assim não funcionar, ou a atualização não estiver listada, você pode gerar o arquivo de tradução manualmente, você deverá utilizar o programa [poedit](https://poedit.net/download).

Utilizando o programa selecione a opção de `Criar uma nova tradução`. Em seguida abra o arquivo `.pot` em `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-extra-checkout-fields-for-brazil/languages`.

Para cada linha do arquivo, você deve preencher a tradução conforme desejar. Em seguida, basta "salvar o arquivo", no mesmo diretório com o nome de `woocommerce-extra-checkout-fields-for-brazil-pt_BR.po`. Automaticamente, também será gerado um arquivo com a extensão `.mo`. Com isto as mensagens devem ser traduzidas.

---

Este é um padrão que é seguido por diversos plugins e temas. Quando os arquivos não estão estão no mesmo diretório do plugin/tema, pode estar em: `wp-content/languages/plugins ou themes`.